# Component template inheritance Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using component inheritance to create some forms for different components.
As off right now, the forms for both components is exactly the same, so I referenced directly the parent .html.

Although it works fine, I would not be able to extend the form for a child component if needed, thus I tried this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'edit-supplier',
template: `<edit-company></edit-company>`,
//templateUrl: '../../models/components/edit-company/edit-company.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-supplier.component.css']
})
```

This seems to be getting the parent template as I wanted, however, the dependency injection seems like is not working.

```
export class EditSupplierComponent extends EditCompanyComponent {
constructor(supplierService: SuplierService,
        router: Router,
        route: ActivatedRoute,
        flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
        settingsService: SettingsService
      ) {
        super(supplierService, router, route, flashMessage, settingsService);
      }
```

This is the edit-company.component.ts

```
@Component({
   selector: 'edit-company',
   templateUrl: './edit-company.component.html',
   providers: [
      {
       provide: CompanyService, 
       useClass: ClientService,
       useValue: 'client', 
      },
      {
        provide: CompanyService,
        useClass: SuplierService,
        useValue: 'supplier', 
      }

  ] 
})

export class EditCompanyComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;
  company: Company = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    balance: 0
  };
  hasBalance: boolean = false;
  showBalanceUpdateInput: boolean;
  parent: string;
  //service: string;
  @ViewChild('editclientForm') form: any;


  //getCompany(id: string): Observable<Company>;
  //updateCompany(company: Company): any;


  constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private settingsService: SettingsService 
  ) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.companyService.getCompany(this.id).subscribe(client => {
      this.company = client;
      this.id = this.company.id;
    });
    this.showBalanceUpdateInput = this.settingsService.getSettings().showBalanceUpdateInput;
  }


  onSubmit({value, valid}: {value: Company, valid: boolean}){
    if(!valid){
      this.flashMessage.show('Please, fill out the form correctly', {
        CssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 4000
      });
    } else {
      value.id = this.id;
      //this.clientService.updateCompany(value).then( () => {
      this.companyService.updateCompany(value).then( () => {
        this.flashMessage.show('Client updated successfuly', {
          cssClass: "alert-success", timeout: 4000
        });
      }, ()=>{
        this.flashMessage.show('Client could not be updated. Try again later.', {
          cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 4000
        });
      });
      this.router.navigate([`/${this.parent}/${this.id}`]);
    }
  }
}
```

> ERROR TypeError: this.companyService.getCompany is not a function
>       at EditCompanyComponent.ngOnInit (edit-company.component.ts:62)
>       at callHook (core.js:3937)
>       at callHooks (core.js:3901)
>       at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:3842)
>       at refreshView (core.js:11795)
>       at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
>       at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
>       at refreshView (core.js:11829)
>       at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
>       at refreshView (core.js:11800)

Does someone have any idea of how to do this the right way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please show more info on why you need to share the template? Maybe you need to think in a different way

Comment: I need to add companies to a database. Come will be clients, some will be suppliers. Right now, the forms are the same, but this is open to change. I generated a parent class for adding companies, and the derived are for clients and for suppliers. The basic info is the same tho.

Comment: Indeed. The better approach is to simply use Inputs and Outputs. Extending components this way is not really the correct solution.

Comment: It would be a good idea to show all relevant code here - especially `EditCompanyComponent`. It seems like `EditCompanyComponent has an injected value - `companyService` - that we can't see here.

Comment: Hi. I updated the original question to reflect the code of EditCompanyComponent.